# OnDestroy() of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

I'm convert from a googledrive example to my class that can handle It easier.
On this example, It call a menthod that return an Intent (this intent used to choose google account).
Main activity call startActivityForResult(intent). and check session & login on onActivityResult.
The googledrive example

```
public class GoogleActivity extends Activity {
    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;

    private static Uri fileUri;
    private static Drive service;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
       //Start account picker here (the intent I've told above)
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
      //credential.newChooseAccountIntent() return an intent that can choose google account
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
                    //Process it when intent exit
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    service = getDriveService(credential);
                    startCameraIntent();
                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                saveFileToDrive();
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
            break;
        case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                saveFileToDrive();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCameraIntent() {
        String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg"));

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
    }

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // File's binary content
                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

                    // File's metadata.
                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

                    File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                    if (file != null) {
                        showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                        startCameraIntent();
                    }
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
    }

    public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now I want to create a class to handle some feature of googledrive including login. My Login() menthod handle everything about login.
I can call Account Picker intent outside main activity but I can't handle when that intent exit/destroy.
My class is something like this:

```
public class GoogleHandler {
    Activity act;

    public GoogleHandler(Activity act) {
        this.act = act;
    }

    public void Login() {
            //start 
        act.startActivity(intent, requestCode);
    }
    // And then, how to handle when intent exit ??
}
```

Any suggestion also helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intent that you pass to `startActivity()` doesn't ever start or finish. That's not what Intents do; Intents start up another Activity (or Service), which then starts and finishes.

When the Google Account Picker Activity finishes, the `onActivityResult()` method of the calling Activity is called. In your example, `act` recvieves a call to `onActivityResult()`. You can see an example of how to properly use the result in the Google Drive sample code you posted.

In order to properly receive this callback, the `act` Activity must override `onActivityResult()`. You cannot do this within the `Login()` method or the `GoogleHandler` class unless you change `GoogleHandler` to an Activity.

Comment: Thanks for help. Can I override onActivityResult of "act" inside GoogleHandler class ??

Comment: No. In Java you must override methods within the class itself.

Comment: Thanks, then there is no way for create a class can handle everything of google as I want?

Comment: If you change your GoogleHandler into an Activity, sure! Or you could redesign the way the two classes interact. Where and how you handle your callbacks and account logic is a design decision that will come down to your personal preferences.

Comment: You are right, I'm moving account picker to my activity then It can work normally. Thanks for help my basic question :)